# Padding-top não funciona no conteudo abaixo do navbar do bootstrap, no navegador firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

**Contexto:**
Estou usando Bootstrap como framework para a parte de interface e django para a parte de regras de negocio e acesso ao banco de dados de um site que estou desenvolvendo.

**O problema:**
Tenho duas navbar, uma para o menu no top e outra para o rodapé.
Porém, quando vou adicionar conteúdo logo abaixo do navbar, o conteúdo fica escondido atrás da navbar. Mas isso só acontece no firefox.

Já adicionei *padding-top* na tag *container* onde será o conteúdo logo abaixo da navbar, mas o conteúdo não fica por trás da navbar.
Também já usei o *-moz, @-moz-document e z-index* mas nada aconteceu.

**Código html da página em questão:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>LEDS - Laborátorio de Sistemas Embarcados e Distribuidos</title>
        <script src="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.2/js/jquery-1.11.2.js' %}"></script>
        <link href="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    </head>
{#    class gradiente deixa o background padrao com duas cores do topo pro bottom#}
    <body class="gradient">
    <!-- NAVBAR
    ================================================== -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="{% url 'core:home' %}">
                <img data-holder-rendered="true" src="/media/customLogo2.png" class="featurette-image img-responsive"
                     data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="300x80"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'core:home' %}">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">LEDS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Publicações</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'documentos-tecnicos:documentos_tecnicos' %}">Documentos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Eventos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Quem Somos<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Associados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Parceiros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">O laboratório</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <p class="navbar-text">Bem vindo, {{ user }}</p>
                        <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'contas:logout' %}">Sair <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <p class="navbar-text">Usuario</p>
                        <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'contas:login' %}">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>DOCUMENTOS TÉCNICOS</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="modal-footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">Instituto  (CNPJ: /0010-36)</p>
            <p class="text-muted">Rod. . CEP: 60 | Fone: 6-8100</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

     <script src="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Nenhuma das classes do Bootstrap que eu usei nas navbar e no conteudo foram alteradas.**

Answer (score 2):

O exemplo abaixo funciona corretamente no Chrome e no Firefox. É dado um `margin-top` para os elementos com a classe `container` **exceto** aqueles que estão dentro da `nav`. A razão de usar `margin` e não `padding` é porque se o conteúdo em si for grande - maior ou igual ao *padding* utilizado - seu uso não terá efeito algum, enquanto que com a margem se garante que o conteúdo **comece** abaixo de determinado ponto:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

nav .container {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- NAVBAR
    ================================================== -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="{% url 'core:home' %}">
                <img data-holder-rendered="true" src="/media/customLogo2.png" class="featurette-image img-responsive"
                     data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="300x80"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'core:home' %}">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">LEDS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Publicações</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'documentos-tecnicos:documentos_tecnicos' %}">Documentos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Eventos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Quem Somos<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Associados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Parceiros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">O laboratório</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <p class="navbar-text">Bem vindo, {{ user }}</p>
                        <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'contas:logout' %}">Sair <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <p class="navbar-text">Usuario</p>
                        <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'contas:login' %}">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>DOCUMENTOS TÉCNICOS</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="modal-footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">Instituto  (CNPJ: /0010-36)</p>
            <p class="text-muted">Rod. . CEP: 60 | Fone: 6-8100</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

(quando se rola a tela, é claro, o conteúdo vai pra trás do *navbar* - pois você indicou que o queria fixo no topo)

Comment: ainda sem funcionar no firefox, mas no chrome funcionou.

Comment: @4ndr3 Mas o exemplo acima, funciona? Estou no Firefox 36.0.4 no Windows 7, e não vejo problema algum. Talvez haja algum detalhe diferente no seu código, não sei... (ou quando o Django populou os templates algo importante mudou - aqui só tenho acesso ao HTML básico) Experimente inspecionar os elementos no debugger do Firefox, veja se a regra CSS foi aplicada corretamente, se outra regra teve precedência, etc.

Comment: O exemplo não funcionou, já inspecionei o debugger do Firefox e a regra do CSS não foi aplicada.